# Oracle Display Number

Tags: oracle, numbers, display

We need to take some very large numbers and display them in an abbreviated fashion like this:

```
2113546998.37   --> 21.37B
15481063.31  --> 15.31M
```

And so on.   I do not think Oracle has a method for doing this.  Was hoping for some help.

Comment: You would need to write a custom function for that format, or do the conversion in the application code instead of at the SQL-level. BTW, your math is off: "`2113546998.37`" should be `2.11B` and "`15481063.31`" should be `15.48M`.

Comment: Indeed, rounding billions, but leaving fractions with 2 digit precision is a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use log and power to manipulate and interpret the value; to get it rounded to decimal places for it's nearest 'large number' bracket:

```
round(your_number / power(10, 3 * floor(log(10, your_number) / 3)), 2)
```

And then to get the letter to append, something like:

```
case 3 * floor(log(10, your_number) / 3)
  when 0 then null when 3 then 'K' when 6 then 'M'
  when 9 then 'B' when 12 then 'T' when 15 then 'Q'
end
```

and so on, though if you get larger than that you'll have to decide how to distinguish between quadrillion and quintillion.

With some extended sample data, a full query of:

```
select your_number,
  round(your_number / power(10, 3 * floor(log(10, your_number) / 3)), 2)
  ||
  case 3 * floor(log(10, your_number) / 3)
    when 0 then null when 3 then 'K' when 6 then 'M'
    when 9 then 'B' when 12 then 'T' when 15 then 'Q'
    else 'x'
  end as result
from your_table
order by your_number
```

gets

| YOUR_NUMBER | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| 123.456789 | 123.46 |
| 1234.56789 | 1.23K |
| 12345.6789 | 12.35K |
| 123456.789 | 123.46K |
| 1234567.89 | 1.23M |
| 15481063.31 | 15.48M |
| 123456789 | 123.46M |
| 2113546998.37 | 2.11B |
| 123456789123 | 123.46B |
| 123456789123456 | 123.46T |

So that gets 2.11B and 15.48M for your two original values, not 21.37B
and 15.31M as your question showed - but as pointed out in comments, it wouldn't really make sense to only keep both extremes of the precision. It's possible do do that, of course - floor instead of round, and append the original decimal part - but it seems unlikely that's what you really meant, and I've assume both 21 vs 2 and the decimal parts are mistakes putting the question together.

You might not want to apply it to smaller numbers though - 'K' is perhaps less common? - and if so you could use another case expression to decide. For example:

```
select your_number,
  case
    when log(10, your_number) < 6
    then to_char(round(your_number, 2))
    else
      round(your_number / power(10, 3 * floor(log(10, your_number) / 3)), 2)
      ||
      case 3 * floor(log(10, your_number) / 3)
        when 6 then 'M' when 9 then 'B' when 12 then 'T' when 15 then 'Q'
        else 'x'
      end
  end as result
from your_table
order by your_number
```

| YOUR_NUMBER | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| 123.456789 | 123.46 |
| 1234.56789 | 1234.57 |
| 12345.6789 | 12345.68 |
| 123456.789 | 123456.79 |
| 1234567.89 | 1.23M |
| 15481063.31 | 15.48M |
| 123456789 | 123.46M |
| 2113546998.37 | 2.11B |
| 123456789123 | 123.46B |
| 123456789123456 | 123.46T |

Either way you can easily put the logic into a function.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=00af7ae30fcfd6d35f5d7ce9514329d7)

I've only looked at positive, non-zero numbers; if you need to handle zero or negative numbers then it will need [a little bit more work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c482a8294f78136b4c6c172c83e28764).